# How to get list of class files generated by JavaCompiler compilationTask?

Tags: java, classloader, javacompiler

I am trying to compile java code dynamically using javaCompiler. Code works gr8 however I need to get the list of class files created by CompilationTask. Here is source code:

```
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler ();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager (diagnostics,null,null);
    //compile unit
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits =fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles (sourceFileList);
    CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask (null,fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
    task.call ();
```

How can I get the list of classes generated by above code, including inner classed. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it helps considering that all resources are accessed through the provided file manager…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file manager, you provide to the task, is responsible for mapping the abstract `JavaFileObject`s to physical files, so it does not only *know* which resources are accessed or created, it even *controls* which physical resource will be used. Of course, just locating the created resources after the processing, is possible as well. Here is a simple self-contained example:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null,null,null);
Path tmp=Files.createTempDirectory("compile-test-");
fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,Collections.singleton(tmp.toFile()));
Path src=tmp.resolve("A.java");
Files.write(src, Arrays.asList(
        "package test;",
        "class A {",
        "    class B {",
        "    }",
        "}"
));
CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager,
        null, null, null, fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(src.toFile()));
if(task.call()) {
    for(JavaFileObject jfo: fileManager.list(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,
                            "", Collections.singleton(JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS), true)) {
        System.out.println(jfo.getName());
    }
}
```

It will list the locations of the generated `A.class` and `A$B.class`…

Comment: Thank you!! this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The [javax.tools.JavaCompiler#getTask()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) method takes an options parameter that allows to set compiler options. Set the destination directory for class files using `-d` option

```
List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
// Sets the destination directory for class files
options.addAll(Arrays.asList("-d","/home/myclasses"));

CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask (null,fileManager, diagnostics, options, null, compilationUnits);
```

Now get all the files with `.class` extentions