# Create a java class dynamically and compile and instantiate at run time

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime, bytecode, byte-buddy

I have a `String` that I need to convert to java class, compile and create an instance at run time:
Suppose my `String` is:

```
String s = " public class Test {
  public Double add(Double x, Double y){
    return (x+y);
  }
}"
```

How can I convert it to a class `Test`.class, instantiate it and call the method `add(Double x, Double y)` at run time?

I read about `Byte` Buddy , but the examples I see has a class already defined. In a situation like the above, could anyone give an example how can I use ByteBuddy or any other libraries through which I can achieve this?

Any inputs or suggestions on how to convert this `String` to compilable and instantiable java class would be helpful.

Comment: You're going to have to invoke the Java compiler somehow. Which means bundling it with the application. At that point, you can just invoke it through the shell or however else you like.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: There are lots of examples, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39255177/2711488), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41003305/2711488), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888184/2711488), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56466155/2711488), even addressing potential follow-up questions.

Answer (score 3):

Can we use something like this :

```
package com.demo;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.StandardLocation;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringToClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "import com.demo.FormulaAPI; public class FormulaExecutor" +
                " { public Double formula1(FormulaAPI apiReference)" +
                " { System.out.println(apiReference.evaluate(\"10.10\"));  return apiReference.evaluate(\"10.10\"); } }";
        try
        {
            dynamicClass(s, "FormulaExecutor");
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static void dynamicClass(String sourceCode, String className) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        File parent = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File sourceFile = new File(parent, className + ".java");
        sourceFile.deleteOnExit();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sourceFile);
        writer.write(sourceCode);
        writer.close();

        JavaCompiler javaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager standardJavaFileManager = javaCompiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        File parentDir = sourceFile.getParentFile();
        standardJavaFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(parentDir));
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = standardJavaFileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile));
        javaCompiler.getTask(null, standardJavaFileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits).call();
        standardJavaFileManager.close();

        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {parentDir.toURI().toURL()});
        Class<?> dynamicClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass(className);


        Method formula1 = dynamicClass.getDeclaredMethod("formula1", FormulaAPI.class);
        formula1.invoke(dynamicClass.newInstance(), new Object[] {new FormulaAPI()});
    }


}
```

```
package com.demo;

public class FormulaAPI
{
    public Double evaluate(String str)
    {
        return Double.valueOf(str);
    }
}
```

For Now, Method name is hardcoded

```
        Method addMethod = dynamicClass.getDeclaredMethod("add", Double.class, Double.class);
```

We can even generate it at runTime using reflection

We can import the class in the source code.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the solution. I tried the code, but getting the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: on the line : urlClassLoader.loadClass

Comment: I ran it my local machine. It worked for me. I'm using macbook and intellij for development. Can you please share the stack trace. @javaseeker

Comment: The example that you mentioned is working perfect. What  I see is a warning - stack trace below, Any idea why? Cannot paste the entire stack trace as there is word limit in comments, i will paste here in parts

Comment: <..the path..>FormulaExecutor.java:1: warning: Can't initialize javac processor due to (most likely) a class loader problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/processing/JavacProcessingEnvironment

Comment: My source String is:
`public class FormulaExecutor { public Double formula1(FormulaAPI apiReference) { return apiReference.evaluate("L"); } }`

Comment: I am referring to another class -FormulaAPI  -in my source code

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

   at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass(ShadowClassLoader.java:373)

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: this is getting printed in console as a warning

Comment: I have updated the code by adding the import in the source code string . As we need, to  import `FormulaAPI` class. Can you please have a look in this code? Let me know, if any issue. @javaseeker

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy works on the byte code level and does not process source code. You can use Javassist for this purpose which offers limited processing of source code as it ships its own compiler.

Alternatively, use the Java compiler API as suggested.